# Formatting array output into 9x9 box

Tags: java, arrays

I had to write a program for my class that creates a 9x9 multiplication table. I've written the program to where the numbers are correct but I don't know how to format it to where the output is in a 9x9 box. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MultTable
{
 public static void main(String[]args)
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  int multTableSize = 9;
  int[][] multTable = new int[multTableSize][multTableSize];

    for (int row = 0; row < multTable.length; row++)
    {
            for (int column = 0; column < multTable[row].length; column++)
            {
                    multTable[row][column] = (row + 1) * (column + 1);
                            System.out.print(multTable[row][column] + " ");
            }
    }
  System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are adding the line break outside both of your loops, rather than at the end of the first loop, and second, for text formatting, you are better off using `printf()` than `println()`.

Try something like this:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < multTable.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < multTable[row].length; column++) {
            multTable[row][column] = (row + 1) * (column + 1);
            System.out.printf("%3d", multTable[row][column]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

`%3d` is a format string which will make your numbers appear in 3-character wide columns.
See the [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) class docs to learn more about how to format output in Java.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about that until now!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a System.out.println(); after your inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int row = 0; row < multTable.length; row++)
{
        for (int column = 0; column < multTable[row].length; column++)
        {
                multTable[row][column] = (row + 1) * (column + 1);
                        System.out.print(multTable[row][column] + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
}
```

after the end of the second loop --> you need to skip one line..